# Regex that finds unspecified html tags which are not surrounded by specified html tags

Tags: regex, tags

I'm trying to find a Regex that finds all tags that are:

1. NOT part of a list of allowed tags
2. NOT surrounded by a specific tag

This is what I currently have:

```
(?<!<noparse>)<(?!(\/?(noparse|u))).*?>(?!<\/noparse>)
```

If I have the following as input

```
<u><b>test2</b></u>
<noparse><u><b>test</b></u></noparse>
<noparse><b>test</b></noparse>
```

It will match

```
<b> & </b> (correct, not surrounded by <noparse></noparse>, <u></u> is allowed)
<b> & </b> (incorrect, surrounded by <noparse></noparse>)
</b></noparse> (incorrect, surrounded by <noparse></noparse>)
```

However, I'd like it to match

```
<b> & </b>
{nothing}
{nothing}
```

You can check it out here:
https://regex101.com/r/HO1Bo2/1

I want to do this so that I can sanitize strings. Our app is made in Unity and uses TextMeshPro to display text. TMP supports quite a lot of tags, all of which you can find here: http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/ . We only want to allow a couple of these tags, because users could get too creative and start messing with line heights, offsets, fontsize and so on. We also want to use the  tag so that users can surround any supported tag with it to make it show up as plain text.

Thanks in advance, I'm sure there are smarter people than me around!

Yours,
Bas

Comment: Using regex is not the best way to go, here, I think. You may get to a solution faster using something like XPath.

Comment: If you want to parse HTML, use an HTML parser (like AngleSharp or HAP). You should avoid to use regex to parse HTML [cf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)

Comment: I added an explanation on what I want to achieve in the end. A plugin is the parser in this case, and I want to sanitize input strings before they reach the plugin

Comment: This seems barely related to `Unity3d` or `c#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with a different route, because Regex was really not working out in this case.

1. Create a List that will contain all strings that should not be taken into account during the sanitization process
2. Replace all existing format items in the input string with a normalized format item, and backup the original format item in said list.

   ```
   <b>test</b> {56} <noparse><b>test</b></noparse> {3}
   becomes
   <b>test</b> {0} <noparse><b>test</b></noparse> {1}
   ```
3. Replace all existing ... blocks, also with normalized format items, and add them to the same list.

   ```
   <b>test</b> {0} <noparse><b>test</b></noparse> {1}
   becomes
   <b>test</b> {0} {2} {1}
   ```
4. Retrieve all unsupported tags in the remaining string & sanitize, using the following regex:

   ```
   <(?!(\/?(u|i))).*?>
   ```

   The following tags are supported tags in this case, all others will be found by the Regex:

   ```
   <u></u><i></i>
   ```

   Surrounding all unsupported tags with noparse tags leads to the following string:

   ```
   <b>test</b> {0} {2} {1}
   becomes
   <noparse><b></noparse>test<noparse></b></noparse> {0} {2} {1}
   ```
5. Now we can replace all the format items with their original text again

   ```
   string sanitizedString = string.Format(sanitizedStringBuilder.ToString(), replacedStrings.ToArray());
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   <noparse><b></noparse>test<noparse></b></noparse> {56} <noparse><b>test</b></noparse> {3}
   ```

Seems to work really well, and while it's quite a lot of steps I'm pretty happy with this solution.